# android - How to make a recycle view like this

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to make an activity like this , I want to show my latest articles like this ,the big box is the latest article and the other boxes are the latest ones .

[image]

how can I make something like this ? is there any library to do so ?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: That is a [staggered grid view](https://dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android-1)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I agree, your solution is more promising and the OP should consider it.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce how you can handle row span with vertical `GridLayoutManager`?

Comment: @thetonrifles  ...I thought GridLayoutManager can handle that. Apparently it can't... O_o I guess it really **is** a staggered grid. Removed my false claims.

Comment: @Skynet apparently you were correct, GridLayoutManager doesn't know how to do row spans.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I think even `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` is not correct. It allows in some way to have control on the row span, but not on the column span.

Comment: @thetonrifles Good lord. It needs a custom layout manager then.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It seems so. I was also thinking management of this layout could be easy, but I made some attempts with standard layout managers without success.

Comment: err.. complexities galore .. :) Interesting, I am gonna check this out as soon as I am out from office

Comment: @Skynet you are right... this question is becoming more interesting and challenging than expected :D

Comment: Means fun and satisfaction upon unfurling that 'success flag' :D

Comment: I guess the only thing you can really do here is make your own LayoutManager. I did [make one that required you to explicitly specify the width and height of every element and doesn't support predictive animations](https://github.com/Zhuinden/LayoutManagerTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/hu/zhu/vga/layoutmanagertest/preserve/TwoDirectionRecycleLayoutManager.java), that was already fun times... and I think the visibility check is actually bugged as it doesn't seem to check for the vertical scroll. Well, this isn't the final version of what I used eventually.

Comment: I guess the only thing you can really do here is make your own LayoutManager. I did [make one that required you to explicitly specify the width and height of every element and doesn't support predictive animations, that was already fun times](https://github.com/Zhuinden/LayoutManagerTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/hu/zhu/vga/layoutmanagertest/newskeleton/SkeletonUberLayoutManager.java)...

Comment: this may help you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821961/how-to-design-spannable-gridview-using-recyclerview-spannablegridlayoutmanager

Answer (score 1):

```
        final SpannableGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams lp = (SpannableGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams)itemView.getLayoutParams();

        final int span1 = (itemId == 0 || itemId == 3 ? 2 : 1);
        final int span2 = (itemId == 0 ? 2 : (itemId == 3 ? 3 : 1));

        final int colSpan = (isVertical ? span2 : span1);
        final int rowSpan = (isVertical ? span1 : span2);

        if (lp.rowSpan != rowSpan || lp.colSpan != colSpan) {
            lp.rowSpan = rowSpan;
            lp.colSpan = colSpan;
            itemView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
```

https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view is sample can help you