# How to design spannable gridview using recyclerview (SpannableGridLayoutManager)

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, gridlayoutmanager

I want to design grid view like below image provided. The first item should be bigger than the rest.

[image]

Currently I am using `RelativeLayout` with  `GridLayoutManager` check below code

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);    
RecyclerView.LayoutManager  recyclerViewLayoutManager = new 
GridLayoutManager(context, 3);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);
recyclerView_Adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(context,numbers);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerView_Adapter);
```

Dummy array for demo

```
String[] numbers = {
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "four",
        "five",
        "six",
        "seven",
        "eight",
        "nine",
        "ten",
        "eleven",

};
```

Adapter Class

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

String[] values;
Context context1;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context2,String[] values2){

    values = values2;

    context1 = context2;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View v){

        super(v);

        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview1);

    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

    View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context1).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_items,parent,false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder1 = new ViewHolder(view1);

    return viewHolder1;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Vholder, int position){

    Vholder.textView.setText(values[position]);

    Vholder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

    Vholder.textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){

    return values.length;
} }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have implemented the `SpannableGridLayoutManager` for this and its working perfectly for me. Please check the following solution.

> Activity Code

```
SpannableGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new 
SpannableGridLayoutManager(new SpannableGridLayoutManager.GridSpanLookup() {
        @Override
        public SpannableGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo getSpanInfo(int position) 
        {
            if (position == 0) {
                return new SpannableGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(2, 2);
                //this will count of row and column you want to replace
            } else {
                return new SpannableGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(1, 1);
            }
        }
    }, 3, 1f); // 3 is the number of coloumn , how nay to display is 1f

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

> In adapter write following Code

```
public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
     super(itemView);
     GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new 
     GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
     float margin = DimensionUtils.convertDpToPixel(5);
     layoutParams.setMargins((int) margin, (int) margin, (int) margin, 
     (int) margin);
     itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
```

> `SpannableGridLayoutManager` custom class

```
public class SpannableGridLayoutManager extends RecyclerView.LayoutManager {

private GridSpanLookup spanLookup;
private int columns = 1;
private float cellAspectRatio = 1f;

private int cellHeight;
private int[] cellBorders;
private int firstVisiblePosition;
private int lastVisiblePosition;
private int firstVisibleRow;
private int lastVisibleRow;
private boolean forceClearOffsets;
private SparseArray<GridCell> cells;
private List<Integer> firstChildPositionForRow; // key == row, val == first child position
private int totalRows;
private final Rect itemDecorationInsets = new Rect();

public SpannableGridLayoutManager(GridSpanLookup spanLookup, int columns, float cellAspectRatio) {
    this.spanLookup = spanLookup;
    this.columns = columns;
    this.cellAspectRatio = cellAspectRatio;
    setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
}

@Keep /* XML constructor, see RecyclerView#createLayoutManager */
public SpannableGridLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SpannableGridLayoutManager, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    columns = a.getInt(R.styleable.SpannableGridLayoutManager_android_orientation, 1);
    parseAspectRatio(a.getString(R.styleable.SpannableGridLayoutManager_aspectRatio));
    int orientation = a.getInt(R.styleable.SpannableGridLayoutManager_android_orientation, RecyclerView.VERTICAL);

    a.recycle();
    setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
}

public interface GridSpanLookup {
    SpanInfo getSpanInfo(int position);
}

public void setSpanLookup(@NonNull GridSpanLookup spanLookup) {
    this.spanLookup = spanLookup;
}

public static class SpanInfo {
    public int columnSpan;
    public int rowSpan;

    public SpanInfo(int columnSpan, int rowSpan) {
        this.columnSpan = columnSpan;
        this.rowSpan = rowSpan;
    }

    public static final SpanInfo SINGLE_CELL = new SpanInfo(1, 1);
}

public static class LayoutParams extends RecyclerView.LayoutParams {

    int columnSpan;
    int rowSpan;

    public LayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
    }

    public LayoutParams(int width, int height) {
        super(width, height);
    }

    public LayoutParams(ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams source) {
        super(source);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    calculateWindowSize();
    calculateCellPositions(recycler, state);

    if (state.getItemCount() == 0) {
        detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);
        firstVisibleRow = 0;
        resetVisibleItemTracking();
        return;
    }

    // TODO use orientationHelper
    int startTop = getPaddingTop();
    int scrollOffset = 0;
    if (forceClearOffsets) { // see #scrollToPosition
        startTop = -(firstVisibleRow * cellHeight);
        forceClearOffsets = false;
    } else if (getChildCount() != 0) {
        scrollOffset = getDecoratedTop(getChildAt(0));
        startTop = scrollOffset - (firstVisibleRow * cellHeight);
        resetVisibleItemTracking();
    }

    detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);
    int row = firstVisibleRow;
    int availableSpace = getHeight() - scrollOffset;
    int lastItemPosition = state.getItemCount() - 1;
    while (availableSpace > 0 && lastVisiblePosition < lastItemPosition) {
        availableSpace -= layoutRow(row, startTop, recycler, state);
        row = getNextSpannedRow(row);
    }

    layoutDisappearingViews(recycler, state, startTop);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    return new LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    return new LayoutParams(c, attrs);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp) {
    if (lp instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        return new LayoutParams((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) lp);
    } else {
        return new LayoutParams(lp);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean checkLayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp) {
    return lp instanceof LayoutParams;
}

@Override
public void onAdapterChanged(RecyclerView.Adapter oldAdapter, RecyclerView.Adapter newAdapter) {
    removeAllViews();
    reset();
}

@Override
public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollVertically() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (getChildCount() == 0 || dy == 0) return 0;

    int scrolled;
    int top = getDecoratedTop(getChildAt(0));

    if (dy < 0) { // scrolling content down
        if (firstVisibleRow == 0) { // at top of content
            int scrollRange = -(getPaddingTop() - top);
            scrolled = Math.max(dy, scrollRange);
        } else {
            scrolled = dy;
        }
        if (top - scrolled >= 0) { // new top row came on screen
            int newRow = firstVisibleRow - 1;
            if (newRow >= 0) {
                int startOffset = top - (firstVisibleRow * cellHeight);
                layoutRow(newRow, startOffset, recycler, state);
            }
        }
        int firstPositionOfLastRow = getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(lastVisibleRow);
        int lastRowTop = getDecoratedTop(
                getChildAt(firstPositionOfLastRow - firstVisiblePosition));
        if (lastRowTop - scrolled > getHeight()) { // last spanned row scrolled out
            recycleRow(lastVisibleRow, recycler, state);
        }
    } else { // scrolling content up
        int bottom = getDecoratedBottom(getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1));
        if (lastVisiblePosition == getItemCount() - 1) { // is at end of content
            int scrollRange = Math.max(bottom - getHeight() + getPaddingBottom(), 0);
            scrolled = Math.min(dy, scrollRange);
        } else {
            scrolled = dy;
        }
        if ((bottom - scrolled) < getHeight()) { // new row scrolled in
            int nextRow = lastVisibleRow + 1;
            if (nextRow < getSpannedRowCount()) {
                int startOffset = top - (firstVisibleRow * cellHeight);
                layoutRow(nextRow, startOffset, recycler, state);
            }
        }
        int lastPositionInRow = getLastPositionInSpannedRow(firstVisibleRow, state);
        int bottomOfFirstRow =
                getDecoratedBottom(getChildAt(lastPositionInRow - firstVisiblePosition));
        if (bottomOfFirstRow - scrolled < 0) { // first spanned row scrolled out
            recycleRow(firstVisibleRow, recycler, state);
        }
    }
    offsetChildrenVertical(-scrolled);
    return scrolled;
}

@Override
public void scrollToPosition(int position) {
    if (position >= getItemCount()) position = getItemCount() - 1;

    firstVisibleRow = getRowIndex(position);
    resetVisibleItemTracking();
    forceClearOffsets = true;
    removeAllViews();
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(
        RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
    if (position >= getItemCount()) position = getItemCount() - 1;

    LinearSmoothScroller scroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext()) {
        @Override
        public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
            final int rowOffset = getRowIndex(targetPosition) - firstVisibleRow;
            return new PointF(0, rowOffset * cellHeight);
        }
    };
    scroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(scroller);
}

@Override
public int computeVerticalScrollRange(RecyclerView.State state) {
    // TODO update this to incrementally calculate
    return getSpannedRowCount() * cellHeight + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
}

@Override
public int computeVerticalScrollExtent(RecyclerView.State state) {
    return getHeight();
}

@Override
public int computeVerticalScrollOffset(RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (getChildCount() == 0) return 0;
    return getPaddingTop() + (firstVisibleRow * cellHeight) - getDecoratedTop(getChildAt(0));
}

@Override
public View findViewByPosition(int position) {
    if (position < firstVisiblePosition || position > lastVisiblePosition) return null;
    return getChildAt(position - firstVisiblePosition);
}

public int getFirstVisibleItemPosition() {
    return firstVisiblePosition;
}

private static class GridCell {
    final int row;
    final int rowSpan;
    final int column;
    final int columnSpan;

    GridCell(int row, int rowSpan, int column, int columnSpan) {
        this.row = row;
        this.rowSpan = rowSpan;
        this.column = column;
        this.columnSpan = columnSpan;
    }
}

/**
 * This is the main layout algorithm, iterates over all items and places them into [column, row]
 * cell positions. Stores this layout info for use later on. Also records the adapter position
 * that each row starts at.
 * <p>
 * Note that if a row is spanned, then the row start position is recorded as the first cell of
 * the row that the spanned cell starts in. This is to ensure that we have sufficient contiguous
 * views to layout/draw a spanned row.
 */
private void calculateCellPositions(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    final int itemCount = state.getItemCount();
    cells = new SparseArray<>(itemCount);
    firstChildPositionForRow = new ArrayList<>();
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    recordSpannedRowStartPosition(row, column);
    int[] rowHWM = new int[columns]; // row high water mark (per column)
    for (int position = 0; position < itemCount; position++) {

        SpanInfo spanInfo;
        int adapterPosition = recycler.convertPreLayoutPositionToPostLayout(position);
        if (adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            spanInfo = spanLookup.getSpanInfo(adapterPosition);
        } else {
            // item removed from adapter, retrieve its previous span info
            // as we can't get from the lookup (adapter)
            spanInfo = getSpanInfoFromAttachedView(position);
        }

        if (spanInfo.columnSpan > columns) {
            spanInfo.columnSpan = columns; // or should we throw?
        }

        // check horizontal space at current position else start a new row
        // note that this may leave gaps in the grid; we don't backtrack to try and fit
        // subsequent cells into gaps. We place the responsibility on the adapter to provide
        // continuous data i.e. that would not span column boundaries to avoid gaps.
        if (column + spanInfo.columnSpan > columns) {
            row++;
            recordSpannedRowStartPosition(row, position);
            column = 0;
        }

        // check if this cell is already filled (by previous spanning cell)
        while (rowHWM[column] > row) {
            column++;
            if (column + spanInfo.columnSpan > columns) {
                row++;
                recordSpannedRowStartPosition(row, position);
                column = 0;
            }
        }

        // by this point, cell should fit at [column, row]
        cells.put(position, new GridCell(row, spanInfo.rowSpan, column, spanInfo.columnSpan));

        // update the high water mark book-keeping
        for (int columnsSpanned = 0; columnsSpanned < spanInfo.columnSpan; columnsSpanned++) {
            rowHWM[column + columnsSpanned] = row + spanInfo.rowSpan;
        }

        // if we're spanning rows then record the 'first child position' as the first item
        // *in the row the spanned item starts*. i.e. the position might not actually sit
        // within the row but it is the earliest position we need to render in order to fill
        // the requested row.
        if (spanInfo.rowSpan > 1) {
            int rowStartPosition = getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(row);
            for (int rowsSpanned = 1; rowsSpanned < spanInfo.rowSpan; rowsSpanned++) {
                int spannedRow = row + rowsSpanned;
                recordSpannedRowStartPosition(spannedRow, rowStartPosition);
            }
        }

        // increment the current position
        column += spanInfo.columnSpan;
    }
    totalRows = rowHWM[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < rowHWM.length; i++) {
        if (rowHWM[i] > totalRows) {
            totalRows = rowHWM[i];
        }
    }
}

private SpanInfo getSpanInfoFromAttachedView(int position) {
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (position == getPosition(child)) {
            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            return new SpanInfo(lp.columnSpan, lp.rowSpan);
        }
    }
    // errrrr?
    return SpanInfo.SINGLE_CELL;
}

private void recordSpannedRowStartPosition(final int rowIndex, final int position) {
    if (getSpannedRowCount() < (rowIndex + 1)) {
        firstChildPositionForRow.add(position);
    }
}

private int getRowIndex(final int position) {
    return position < cells.size() ? cells.get(position).row : -1;
}

private int getSpannedRowCount() {
    return firstChildPositionForRow.size();
}

private int getNextSpannedRow(int rowIndex) {
    int firstPositionInRow = getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(rowIndex);
    int nextRow = rowIndex + 1;
    while (nextRow < getSpannedRowCount()
            && getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(nextRow) == firstPositionInRow) {
        nextRow++;
    }
    return nextRow;
}

private int getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(int rowIndex) {
    return firstChildPositionForRow.get(rowIndex);
}

private int getLastPositionInSpannedRow(final int rowIndex, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int nextRow = getNextSpannedRow(rowIndex);
    return (nextRow != getSpannedRowCount()) ? // check if reached boundary
            getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(nextRow) - 1
            : state.getItemCount() - 1;
}

/**
 * Lay out a given 'row'. We might actually add more that one row if the requested row contains
 * a row-spanning cell. Returns the pixel height of the rows laid out.
 * <p>
 * To simplify logic & book-keeping, views are attached in adapter order, that is child 0 will
 * always be the earliest position displayed etc.
 */
private int layoutRow(
        int rowIndex, int startTop, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int firstPositionInRow = getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(rowIndex);
    int lastPositionInRow = getLastPositionInSpannedRow(rowIndex, state);
    boolean containsRemovedItems = false;

    int insertPosition = (rowIndex < firstVisibleRow) ? 0 : getChildCount();
    for (int position = firstPositionInRow;
         position <= lastPositionInRow;
         position++, insertPosition++) {

        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        containsRemovedItems |= lp.isItemRemoved();
        GridCell cell = cells.get(position);
        addView(view, insertPosition);

        // TODO use orientation helper
        int wSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(
                cellBorders[cell.column + cell.columnSpan] - cellBorders[cell.column],
                View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, 0, lp.width, false);
        int hSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(cell.rowSpan * cellHeight,
                View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, 0, lp.height, true);
        measureChildWithDecorationsAndMargin(view, wSpec, hSpec);

        int left = cellBorders[cell.column] + lp.leftMargin;
        int top = startTop + (cell.row * cellHeight) + lp.topMargin;
        int right = left + getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view);
        int bottom = top + getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view);
        layoutDecorated(view, left, top, right, bottom);
        lp.columnSpan = cell.columnSpan;
        lp.rowSpan = cell.rowSpan;
    }

    if (firstPositionInRow < firstVisiblePosition) {
        firstVisiblePosition = firstPositionInRow;
        firstVisibleRow = getRowIndex(firstVisiblePosition);
    }
    if (lastPositionInRow > lastVisiblePosition) {
        lastVisiblePosition = lastPositionInRow;
        lastVisibleRow = getRowIndex(lastVisiblePosition);
    }
    if (containsRemovedItems) return 0; // don't consume space for rows with disappearing items

    GridCell first = cells.get(firstPositionInRow);
    GridCell last = cells.get(lastPositionInRow);
    return (last.row + last.rowSpan - first.row) * cellHeight;
}

/**
 * Remove and recycle all items in this 'row'. If the row includes a row-spanning cell then all
 * cells in the spanned rows will be removed.
 */
private void recycleRow(
        int rowIndex, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int firstPositionInRow = getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(rowIndex);
    int lastPositionInRow = getLastPositionInSpannedRow(rowIndex, state);
    int toRemove = lastPositionInRow;
    while (toRemove >= firstPositionInRow) {
        int index = toRemove - firstVisiblePosition;
        removeAndRecycleViewAt(index, recycler);
        toRemove--;
    }
    if (rowIndex == firstVisibleRow) {
        firstVisiblePosition = lastPositionInRow + 1;
        firstVisibleRow = getRowIndex(firstVisiblePosition);
    }
    if (rowIndex == lastVisibleRow) {
        lastVisiblePosition = firstPositionInRow - 1;
        lastVisibleRow = getRowIndex(lastVisiblePosition);
    }
}

private void layoutDisappearingViews(
        RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int startTop) {
    // TODO
}

private void calculateWindowSize() {
    // TODO use OrientationHelper#getTotalSpace
    int cellWidth =
            (int) Math.floor((getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()) / columns);
    cellHeight = (int) Math.floor(cellWidth * (1f / cellAspectRatio));
    calculateCellBorders();
}

private void reset() {
    cells = null;
    firstChildPositionForRow = null;
    firstVisiblePosition = 0;
    firstVisibleRow = 0;
    lastVisiblePosition = 0;
    lastVisibleRow = 0;
    cellHeight = 0;
    forceClearOffsets = false;
}

private void resetVisibleItemTracking() {
    // maintain the firstVisibleRow but reset other state vars
    // TODO make orientation agnostic
    int minimumVisibleRow = getMinimumFirstVisibleRow();
    if (firstVisibleRow > minimumVisibleRow) firstVisibleRow = minimumVisibleRow;
    firstVisiblePosition = getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(firstVisibleRow);
    lastVisibleRow = firstVisibleRow;
    lastVisiblePosition = firstVisiblePosition;
}

private int getMinimumFirstVisibleRow() {
    int maxDisplayedRows = (int) Math.ceil((float) getHeight() / cellHeight) + 1;
    if (totalRows < maxDisplayedRows) return 0;
    int minFirstRow = totalRows - maxDisplayedRows;
    // adjust to spanned rows
    return getRowIndex(getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(minFirstRow));
}

/* Adapted from GridLayoutManager */

private void calculateCellBorders() {
    cellBorders = new int[columns + 1];
    int totalSpace = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    int consumedPixels = getPaddingLeft();
    cellBorders[0] = consumedPixels;
    int sizePerSpan = totalSpace / columns;
    int sizePerSpanRemainder = totalSpace % columns;
    int additionalSize = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
        int itemSize = sizePerSpan;
        additionalSize += sizePerSpanRemainder;
        if (additionalSize > 0 && (columns - additionalSize) < sizePerSpanRemainder) {
            itemSize += 1;
            additionalSize -= columns;
        }
        consumedPixels += itemSize;
        cellBorders[i] = consumedPixels;
    }
}

private void measureChildWithDecorationsAndMargin(View child, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    calculateItemDecorationsForChild(child, itemDecorationInsets);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    widthSpec = updateSpecWithExtra(widthSpec, lp.leftMargin + itemDecorationInsets.left,
            lp.rightMargin + itemDecorationInsets.right);
    heightSpec = updateSpecWithExtra(heightSpec, lp.topMargin + itemDecorationInsets.top,
            lp.bottomMargin + itemDecorationInsets.bottom);
    child.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
}

private int updateSpecWithExtra(int spec, int startInset, int endInset) {
    if (startInset == 0 && endInset == 0) {
        return spec;
    }
    int mode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(spec);
    if (mode == View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST || mode == View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        return View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                View.MeasureSpec.getSize(spec) - startInset - endInset, mode);
    }
    return spec;
}

/* Adapted from ConstraintLayout */

private void parseAspectRatio(String aspect) {
    if (aspect != null) {
        int colonIndex = aspect.indexOf(':');
        if (colonIndex >= 0 && colonIndex < aspect.length() - 1) {
            String nominator = aspect.substring(0, colonIndex);
            String denominator = aspect.substring(colonIndex + 1);
            if (nominator.length() > 0 && denominator.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    float nominatorValue = Float.parseFloat(nominator);
                    float denominatorValue = Float.parseFloat(denominator);
                    if (nominatorValue > 0 && denominatorValue > 0) {
                        cellAspectRatio = Math.abs(nominatorValue / denominatorValue);
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            }
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse aspect ratio: '" + aspect + "'");
}}
```

> add following code to attr file

```
  <declare-styleable name="SpannableGridLayoutManager">
    <attr name="android:orientation" />
    <attr name="spanCount" />
    <attr name="aspectRatio" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: @Sagar_Hudge can post the attrs

Comment: In nested ScrollView RecylerView is not working. Please Help if possible

Comment: I tried the above class. It is working if you have more than 1 row. It is not working for 1 row. For example- if you have 3 column in row 1 and you have only 1 element in the first row to show then it is not showing anything on the screen.

Comment: @ChhatrasalSinghBundela, Please check this commit [https://github.com/android/plaid/commit/a14eb290a9ad80434e063a466ee82ad44d06950c#diff-1e986e17c47052bd2f89586e1f89f6ce]

Comment: @Sagar Thank you so much! it was exactly what I needed. However, I have issue with nested scrolling. I don't want to have scrolling inside the recycler view. So I changed canScrollVertically to false but then it does not show all contents. Is there any solution for this?

Additionally, is there any updated version of this class (hopefully in Kotlin)? 
thanks again

Comment: @MehdiSatei It's been a long time that I have worked on. Please have search for `SpannableGridLayoutManager ` you will find many results that hope may help you. I will try to get back on this

Comment: @Sagar I have searched on this. Unfortunately it has not been any new updates on it. That would be great!

Comment: @Sagar Hey a quick question, Can I change the orientation to Horizontal? If so, what should I change? Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for the link to the "plaid" app! I found what I needed after so many hours of searching