# Dynamic width item in recyclerview Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout, staggeredgridlayout

i want to make dynamic width items in recyclerview as shown in below image.

[image]

I'd tried a lot for finding solution but i didn't found any perfect solution. i found solution that we can create dynamic size items using StaggeredGridLayout but as i think, it only works with vertically dynamic size. i want to add items having horizontal dynamic sizes. how can i achieve that? please tell me if anyone knows. Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: Modify as you want : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48825958/7319704