# How to spread evenly two view types with different sizes in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've added a new view type for the native ad view in my RecyclerView but I can't figure out how to spread the items evenly across the entire screen. After every 12th element, the new view type should be inserted.

This is what I want:

[image]

And this is what I get:

[image]

The result from the 2nd picture is achieved using this code:

```java
gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mActivity, 6);
        gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                switch (emotesAdapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
                    case AD_TYPE:
                        return gridLayoutManager.getSpanCount();
                    case CONTENT_TYPE:
                        return 1;
                    default:
                        return -1;
                }
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `GridLayoutManager` you can span items horizontally, not vertically and therefore you got:

[image]

So, you can't do that with `GridLayoutManager` alone; but you need a customized `LayoutManager` for that; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821961/how-to-design-spannable-gridview-using-recyclerview-spannablegridlayoutmanager/48825958#48825958) provides `SpannableGridLayoutManager` that customizes span size both horizontally and vertically in:

```
public class SpannableGridLayoutManager extends RecyclerView.LayoutManager {

    private GridSpanLookup spanLookup;
    private final int columns;
    private float cellAspectRatio = 1f;

    private int cellHeight;
    private int[] cellBorders;
    private int firstVisiblePosition;
    private int lastVisiblePosition;
    private int firstVisibleRow;
    private int lastVisibleRow;
    private boolean forceClearOffsets;
    private SparseArray<GridCell> cells;
    private List<Integer> firstChildPositionForRow; // key == row, val == first child position
    private int totalRows;
    private final Rect itemDecorationInsets = new Rect();

    public SpannableGridLayoutManager(GridSpanLookup spanLookup, int columns) {
        this.spanLookup = spanLookup;
        this.columns = columns;
    }


    public interface GridSpanLookup {
        SpanInfo getSpanInfo(int position);
    }

    public void setSpanLookup(@NonNull GridSpanLookup spanLookup) {
        this.spanLookup = spanLookup;
    }

    public static class SpanInfo {
        public int columnSpan;
        public int rowSpan;

        public SpanInfo(int columnSpan, int rowSpan) {
            this.columnSpan = columnSpan;
            this.rowSpan = rowSpan;
        }

        public static final SpanInfo SINGLE_CELL = new SpanInfo(1, 1);
    }

    public static class LayoutParams extends RecyclerView.LayoutParams {

        int columnSpan;
        int rowSpan;

        public LayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(c, attrs);
        }

        public LayoutParams(int width, int height) {
            super(width, height);
        }

        public LayoutParams(ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams source) {
            super(source);
        }

        public LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams source) {
            super(source);
        }

        public LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams source) {
            super(source);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        calculateWindowSize();
        calculateCellPositions(recycler, state);

        if (state.getItemCount() == 0) {
            detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);
            firstVisibleRow = 0;
            resetVisibleItemTracking();
            return;
        }

        // TODO use orientationHelper
        int startTop = getPaddingTop();
        int scrollOffset = 0;
        if (forceClearOffsets) { // see #scrollToPosition
            startTop = -(firstVisibleRow * cellHeight);
            forceClearOffsets = false;
        } else if (getChildCount() != 0) {
            scrollOffset = getDecoratedTop(getChildAt(0));
            startTop = scrollOffset - (firstVisibleRow * cellHeight);
            resetVisibleItemTracking();
        }

        detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);
        int row = firstVisibleRow;
        int availableSpace = getHeight() - scrollOffset;
        int lastItemPosition = state.getItemCount() - 1;
        while (availableSpace > 0 && lastVisiblePosition < lastItemPosition) {
            availableSpace -= layoutRow(row, startTop, recycler, state);
            row = getNextSpannedRow(row);
        }

        layoutDisappearingViews(recycler, state, startTop);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
        return new LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        return new LayoutParams(c, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp) {
        if (lp instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
            return new LayoutParams((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) lp);
        } else {
            return new LayoutParams(lp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkLayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp) {
        return lp instanceof LayoutParams;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdapterChanged(RecyclerView.Adapter oldAdapter, RecyclerView.Adapter newAdapter) {
        removeAllViews();
        reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (getChildCount() == 0 || dy == 0) return 0;

        int scrolled;
        int top = getDecoratedTop(getChildAt(0));

        if (dy < 0) { // scrolling content down
            if (firstVisibleRow == 0) { // at top of content
                int scrollRange = -(getPaddingTop() - top);
                scrolled = Math.max(dy, scrollRange);
            } else {
                scrolled = dy;
            }
            if (top - scrolled >= 0) { // new top row came on screen
                int newRow = firstVisibleRow - 1;
                if (newRow >= 0) {
                    int startOffset = top - (firstVisibleRow * cellHeight);
                    layoutRow(newRow, startOffset, recycler, state);
                }
            }
            int firstPositionOfLastRow = getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(lastVisibleRow);
            int lastRowTop = getDecoratedTop(
                    getChildAt(firstPositionOfLastRow - firstVisiblePosition));
            if (lastRowTop - scrolled > getHeight()) { // last spanned row scrolled out
                recycleRow(lastVisibleRow, recycler, state);
            }
        } else { // scrolling content up
            int bottom = getDecoratedBottom(getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1));
            if (lastVisiblePosition == getItemCount() - 1) { // is at end of content
                int scrollRange = Math.max(bottom - getHeight() + getPaddingBottom(), 0);
                scrolled = Math.min(dy, scrollRange);
            } else {
                scrolled = dy;
            }
            if ((bottom - scrolled) < getHeight()) { // new row scrolled in
                int nextRow = lastVisibleRow + 1;
                if (nextRow < getSpannedRowCount()) {
                    int startOffset = top - (firstVisibleRow * cellHeight);
                    layoutRow(nextRow, startOffset, recycler, state);
                }
            }
            int lastPositionInRow = getLastPositionInSpannedRow(firstVisibleRow, state);
            int bottomOfFirstRow =
                    getDecoratedBottom(getChildAt(lastPositionInRow - firstVisiblePosition));
            if (bottomOfFirstRow - scrolled < 0) { // first spanned row scrolled out
                recycleRow(firstVisibleRow, recycler, state);
            }
        }
        offsetChildrenVertical(-scrolled);
        return scrolled;
    }

    @Override
    public void scrollToPosition(int position) {
        if (position >= getItemCount()) position = getItemCount() - 1;

        firstVisibleRow = getRowIndex(position);
        resetVisibleItemTracking();
        forceClearOffsets = true;
        removeAllViews();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(
            RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
        if (position >= getItemCount()) position = getItemCount() - 1;

        LinearSmoothScroller scroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext()) {
            @Override
            public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
                final int rowOffset = getRowIndex(targetPosition) - firstVisibleRow;
                return new PointF(0, rowOffset * cellHeight);
            }
        };
        scroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(scroller);
    }

    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollRange(@NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
        // TODO update this to incrementally calculate
        return getSpannedRowCount() * cellHeight + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
    }

    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollExtent(@NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
        return getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollOffset(@NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (getChildCount() == 0) return 0;
        return getPaddingTop() + (firstVisibleRow * cellHeight) - getDecoratedTop(getChildAt(0));
    }

    @Override
    public View findViewByPosition(int position) {
        if (position < firstVisiblePosition || position > lastVisiblePosition) return null;
        return getChildAt(position - firstVisiblePosition);
    }

    public int getFirstVisibleItemPosition() {
        return firstVisiblePosition;
    }

    private static class GridCell {
        final int row;
        final int rowSpan;
        final int column;
        final int columnSpan;

        GridCell(int row, int rowSpan, int column, int columnSpan) {
            this.row = row;
            this.rowSpan = rowSpan;
            this.column = column;
            this.columnSpan = columnSpan;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main layout algorithm, iterates over all items and places them into [column, row]
     * cell positions. Stores this layout info for use later on. Also records the adapter position
     * that each row starts at.
     * <p>
     * Note that if a row is spanned, then the row start position is recorded as the first cell of
     * the row that the spanned cell starts in. This is to ensure that we have sufficient contiguous
     * views to layout/draw a spanned row.
     */
    private void calculateCellPositions(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        final int itemCount = state.getItemCount();
        cells = new SparseArray<>(itemCount);
        firstChildPositionForRow = new ArrayList<>();
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        recordSpannedRowStartPosition(row, column);
        int[] rowHWM = new int[columns]; // row high water mark (per column)
        for (int position = 0; position < itemCount; position++) {

            SpanInfo spanInfo;
            int adapterPosition = recycler.convertPreLayoutPositionToPostLayout(position);
            if (adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                spanInfo = spanLookup.getSpanInfo(adapterPosition);
            } else {
                // item removed from adapter, retrieve its previous span info
                // as we can't get from the lookup (adapter)
                spanInfo = getSpanInfoFromAttachedView(position);
            }

            if (spanInfo.columnSpan > columns) {
                spanInfo.columnSpan = columns; // or should we throw?
            }

            // check horizontal space at current position else start a new row
            // note that this may leave gaps in the grid; we don't backtrack to try and fit
            // subsequent cells into gaps. We place the responsibility on the adapter to provide
            // continuous data i.e. that would not span column boundaries to avoid gaps.
            if (column + spanInfo.columnSpan > columns) {
                row++;
                recordSpannedRowStartPosition(row, position);
                column = 0;
            }

            // check if this cell is already filled (by previous spanning cell)
            while (rowHWM[column] > row) {
                column++;
                if (column + spanInfo.columnSpan > columns) {
                    row++;
                    recordSpannedRowStartPosition(row, position);
                    column = 0;
                }
            }

            // by this point, cell should fit at [column, row]
            cells.put(position, new GridCell(row, spanInfo.rowSpan, column, spanInfo.columnSpan));

            // update the high water mark book-keeping
            for (int columnsSpanned = 0; columnsSpanned < spanInfo.columnSpan; columnsSpanned++) {
                rowHWM[column + columnsSpanned] = row + spanInfo.rowSpan;
            }

            // if we're spanning rows then record the 'first child position' as the first item
            // *in the row the spanned item starts*. i.e. the position might not actually sit
            // within the row but it is the earliest position we need to render in order to fill
            // the requested row.
            if (spanInfo.rowSpan > 1) {
                int rowStartPosition = getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(row);
                for (int rowsSpanned = 1; rowsSpanned < spanInfo.rowSpan; rowsSpanned++) {
                    int spannedRow = row + rowsSpanned;
                    recordSpannedRowStartPosition(spannedRow, rowStartPosition);
                }
            }

            // increment the current position
            column += spanInfo.columnSpan;
        }
        totalRows = rowHWM[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < rowHWM.length; i++) {
            if (rowHWM[i] > totalRows) {
                totalRows = rowHWM[i];
            }
        }
    }

    private SpanInfo getSpanInfoFromAttachedView(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (position == getPosition(child)) {
                LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                return new SpanInfo(lp.columnSpan, lp.rowSpan);
            }
        }
        // errrrr?
        return SpanInfo.SINGLE_CELL;
    }

    private void recordSpannedRowStartPosition(final int rowIndex, final int position) {
        if (getSpannedRowCount() < (rowIndex + 1)) {
            firstChildPositionForRow.add(position);
        }
    }

    private int getRowIndex(final int position) {
        return position < cells.size() ? cells.get(position).row : -1;
    }

    private int getSpannedRowCount() {
        return firstChildPositionForRow.size();
    }

    private int getNextSpannedRow(int rowIndex) {
        int firstPositionInRow = getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(rowIndex);
        int nextRow = rowIndex + 1;
        while (nextRow < getSpannedRowCount()
                && getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(nextRow) == firstPositionInRow) {
            nextRow++;
        }
        return nextRow;
    }

    private int getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(int rowIndex) {
        return firstChildPositionForRow.get(rowIndex);
    }

    private int getLastPositionInSpannedRow(final int rowIndex, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int nextRow = getNextSpannedRow(rowIndex);
        return (nextRow != getSpannedRowCount()) ? // check if reached boundary
                getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(nextRow) - 1
                : state.getItemCount() - 1;
    }

    /**
     * Lay out a given 'row'. We might actually add more that one row if the requested row contains
     * a row-spanning cell. Returns the pixel height of the rows laid out.
     * <p>
     * To simplify logic & book-keeping, views are attached in adapter order, that is child 0 will
     * always be the earliest position displayed etc.
     */
    private int layoutRow(
            int rowIndex, int startTop, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int firstPositionInRow = getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(rowIndex);
        int lastPositionInRow = getLastPositionInSpannedRow(rowIndex, state);
        boolean containsRemovedItems = false;

        int insertPosition = (rowIndex < firstVisibleRow) ? 0 : getChildCount();
        for (int position = firstPositionInRow;
             position <= lastPositionInRow;
             position++, insertPosition++) {

            View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            containsRemovedItems |= lp.isItemRemoved();
            GridCell cell = cells.get(position);
            addView(view, insertPosition);

            // TODO use orientation helper
            int wSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(
                    cellBorders[cell.column + cell.columnSpan] - cellBorders[cell.column],
                    View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, 0, lp.width, false);
            int hSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(cell.rowSpan * cellHeight,
                    View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, 0, lp.height, true);
            measureChildWithDecorationsAndMargin(view, wSpec, hSpec);

            int left = cellBorders[cell.column] + lp.leftMargin;
            int top = startTop + (cell.row * cellHeight) + lp.topMargin;
            int right = left + getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view);
            int bottom = top + getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view);
            layoutDecorated(view, left, top, right, bottom);
            lp.columnSpan = cell.columnSpan;
            lp.rowSpan = cell.rowSpan;
        }

        if (firstPositionInRow < firstVisiblePosition) {
            firstVisiblePosition = firstPositionInRow;
            firstVisibleRow = getRowIndex(firstVisiblePosition);
        }
        if (lastPositionInRow > lastVisiblePosition) {
            lastVisiblePosition = lastPositionInRow;
            lastVisibleRow = getRowIndex(lastVisiblePosition);
        }
        if (containsRemovedItems) return 0; // don't consume space for rows with disappearing items

        GridCell first = cells.get(firstPositionInRow);
        GridCell last = cells.get(lastPositionInRow);
        return (last.row + last.rowSpan - first.row) * cellHeight;
    }

    /**
     * Remove and recycle all items in this 'row'. If the row includes a row-spanning cell then all
     * cells in the spanned rows will be removed.
     */
    private void recycleRow(
            int rowIndex, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int firstPositionInRow = getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(rowIndex);
        int lastPositionInRow = getLastPositionInSpannedRow(rowIndex, state);
        int toRemove = lastPositionInRow;
        while (toRemove >= firstPositionInRow) {
            int index = toRemove - firstVisiblePosition;
            removeAndRecycleViewAt(index, recycler);
            toRemove--;
        }
        if (rowIndex == firstVisibleRow) {
            firstVisiblePosition = lastPositionInRow + 1;
            firstVisibleRow = getRowIndex(firstVisiblePosition);
        }
        if (rowIndex == lastVisibleRow) {
            lastVisiblePosition = firstPositionInRow - 1;
            lastVisibleRow = getRowIndex(lastVisiblePosition);
        }
    }

    private void layoutDisappearingViews(
            RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int startTop) {
        // TODO
    }

    private void calculateWindowSize() {
        // TODO use OrientationHelper#getTotalSpace
        int cellWidth =
                (int) Math.floor((getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()) / columns);
        cellHeight = (int) Math.floor(cellWidth * (1f / cellAspectRatio));
        calculateCellBorders();
    }

    private void reset() {
        cells = null;
        firstChildPositionForRow = null;
        firstVisiblePosition = 0;
        firstVisibleRow = 0;
        lastVisiblePosition = 0;
        lastVisibleRow = 0;
        cellHeight = 0;
        forceClearOffsets = false;
    }

    private void resetVisibleItemTracking() {
        // maintain the firstVisibleRow but reset other state vars
        // TODO make orientation agnostic
        int minimumVisibleRow = getMinimumFirstVisibleRow();
        if (firstVisibleRow > minimumVisibleRow) firstVisibleRow = minimumVisibleRow;
        firstVisiblePosition = getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(firstVisibleRow);
        lastVisibleRow = firstVisibleRow;
        lastVisiblePosition = firstVisiblePosition;
    }

    private int getMinimumFirstVisibleRow() {
        int maxDisplayedRows = (int) Math.ceil((float) getHeight() / cellHeight) + 1;
        if (totalRows < maxDisplayedRows) return 0;
        int minFirstRow = totalRows - maxDisplayedRows;
        // adjust to spanned rows
        return getRowIndex(getFirstPositionInSpannedRow(minFirstRow));
    }

    /* Adapted from GridLayoutManager */

    private void calculateCellBorders() {
        cellBorders = new int[columns + 1];
        int totalSpace = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        int consumedPixels = getPaddingLeft();
        cellBorders[0] = consumedPixels;
        int sizePerSpan = totalSpace / columns;
        int sizePerSpanRemainder = totalSpace % columns;
        int additionalSize = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
            int itemSize = sizePerSpan;
            additionalSize += sizePerSpanRemainder;
            if (additionalSize > 0 && (columns - additionalSize) < sizePerSpanRemainder) {
                itemSize += 1;
                additionalSize -= columns;
            }
            consumedPixels += itemSize;
            cellBorders[i] = consumedPixels;
        }
    }

    private void measureChildWithDecorationsAndMargin(View child, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        calculateItemDecorationsForChild(child, itemDecorationInsets);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        widthSpec = updateSpecWithExtra(widthSpec, lp.leftMargin + itemDecorationInsets.left,
                lp.rightMargin + itemDecorationInsets.right);
        heightSpec = updateSpecWithExtra(heightSpec, lp.topMargin + itemDecorationInsets.top,
                lp.bottomMargin + itemDecorationInsets.bottom);
        child.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
    }

    private int updateSpecWithExtra(int spec, int startInset, int endInset) {
        if (startInset == 0 && endInset == 0) {
            return spec;
        }
        int mode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(spec);
        if (mode == View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST || mode == View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            return View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    View.MeasureSpec.getSize(spec) - startInset - endInset, mode);
        }
        return spec;
    }

    /* Adapted from ConstraintLayout */

    private void parseAspectRatio(String aspect) {
        if (aspect != null) {
            int colonIndex = aspect.indexOf(':');
            if (colonIndex >= 0 && colonIndex < aspect.length() - 1) {
                String nominator = aspect.substring(0, colonIndex);
                String denominator = aspect.substring(colonIndex + 1);
                if (nominator.length() > 0 && denominator.length() > 0) {
                    try {
                        float nominatorValue = Float.parseFloat(nominator);
                        float denominatorValue = Float.parseFloat(denominator);
                        if (nominatorValue > 0 && denominatorValue > 0) {
                            cellAspectRatio = Math.abs(nominatorValue / denominatorValue);
                            return;
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        // Ignore
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse aspect ratio: '" + aspect + "'");
    }
}
```

Then you can customize the span size for the twelveth item during construction:

```
SpannableGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new
        SpannableGridLayoutManager(position -> {
    if (position == 12) {
        return new SpannableGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(2, 2); // Setting horizontal & vertical span size

    } else {
        return new SpannableGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(1, 1);
    }
}, 6); // 6 is the number of column

recyclerview.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

[image]

This is the used adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View listItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(listItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if (position < 12)
            holder.tvItemNo.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
        else if (position == 12)
            holder.tvItemNo.setText("1");
        else
            holder.tvItemNo.setText(String.valueOf(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 32;
    }

    class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvItemNo;

        CustomViewHolder(@NonNull View listItem) {
            super(listItem);
            GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new
                    GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            float margin = convertDpToPixel(listItem.getResources(), 10);
            layoutParams.setMargins((int) margin, (int) margin, (int) margin,
                    (int) margin);
            listItem.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            tvItemNo = listItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_no);

        }

    }

    private float convertDpToPixel(Resources r, int dp) {
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                dp,
                r.getDisplayMetrics()
        );
    }

}
```

> After every 12th element, the new view type should be inserted.
> Likewise you can add do some checks do achieve that:

```
SpannableGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new
        SpannableGridLayoutManager(position -> {
    int offset = position / 12 - 1;
    if ((position + 1) % 12 != 0 && (position - offset) % 12 == 0) {
        return new SpannableGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(2, 2);
    } else {
        return new SpannableGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(1, 1);
    }
}, 6);
```

[image]

### UPDATE:

> The top mentioned method has some issues when scrolling the RecyclerView like adding extra space or changing cell height. There is an expensive solution to notifyDataSetChanged() when the scrolling is over:

```
recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) 
            runOnUiThread(() -> adapter.notifyDataSetChanged());
    }
});
```

But this is expensive, and still there are glitches until the UI is updated.

---

### Another Solution

You can use the `SpannedGridLayoutManager` from [here](https://github.com/noowenz/SpannedGridLayoutManager); it has no extra spaces, item resizing, or glitches issues:

Usage:

```
val spannedGridLayoutManager = SpannedGridLayoutManager(
    orientation = SpannedGridLayoutManager.Orientation.VERTICAL,
    spans = 6
).apply {
    itemOrderIsStable = true
    spanSizeLookup =
        SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup { position ->
            val offset = position / 12 - 1
            if ((position + 1) % 12 != 0 && (position - offset) % 12 == 0) {
                SpanSize(2, 2)
            } else {
                SpanSize(1, 1)
            }
        }
}

val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
recyclerView.apply {
    layoutManager = spannedGridLayoutManager
    adapter = RecyclerAdapter()
}
```

Comment: It's not perfect yet but I see some potential in the second solution and I'll fork the main repo to make some changes to suit my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## **Option 1:**

Use Nick Butcher's [SpannedGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/blob/6a3cb17ede0ffeffb4ca16e4fd3c2ab60900d6b8/app/src/main/java/io/plaidapp/ui/recyclerview/SpannedGridLayoutManager.java) as a lyout manager for your RecyclerView

**Example:**

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new SpannedGridLayoutManager(
        new SpannedGridLayoutManager.GridSpanLookup() {
            @Override
            public SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo getSpanInfo(int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    return new SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(2, 2);
                } else {
                    return new SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(1, 1);
                }
            }
        }, 
        3 /* 3 columns */, 
        1f /* We want our items to be 1:1 ratio */));
```

## **Option 2:**

Use [FlexboxLayoutManager (within RecyclerView)](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview)

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) context.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.COLUMN);
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_END);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

```
mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mImageView.getLayoutParams();
if (lp instanceof FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) {
    FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams flexboxLp = (FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) lp;
    flexboxLp.setFlexGrow(1.0f);
    flexboxLp.setAlignSelf(AlignSelf.FLEX_END);
}
```

It gives decent performance

[image]

Comment: I've already tried and it works but unfortunately, when you are fast scrolling, the items are gone and then just popping up which is a very bad UX...

Comment: @MoisoniIoan I've added 2nd option, please check it out

Comment: still doesn't work. I have tried all possible combinations and even tried the exact same code as the sample app but I can not achieve the desired design